# Dbeaver automatically puts letters behind my queries

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

Dbeaver automatically puts the starting letters of the table behind the full name, if i select a table with the drop down menue and i need to know how to turn it off.

Its like this:

```
select * from kalibrierprotokoll_lx_punkte klp
```

Comment: that table alias is interesting, keep it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DBeaver will create table aliases automatically.

If your table is called `MySpecialTable` then it will use the alias `mst`, if it's called `kalibrierprotokoll_lx_punkte` it will create `klp`.

That's a useful feature later, when you start joining your tables, because it will make it much easier to refer to specific fields using the alias (`klp.something`). It also will make autocomplete column names possible when you start typing `klp.`.

If you must switch it off, you can do so in the Preferences, under

DBeaver → Editors → SQL Editor → SQL Completion → [x] Insert table aliases (in FROM clause)

I would leave it on.

Comment: I just need it to copy paste the code into vba once i am ready i will turn it back on. Thank you

Comment: @Jan  Table aliases won't hurt in your VBA code, I wouldn't even bother. :)

Comment: As of DBeaver v21, this setting can be now be found under Window -> Preferences -> Editors -> SQL Editor -> Code Completion -> Insert Table Alias -> N/A

Comment: Remeber not to query like below, i was stuck on it
`select  kp."columnName" from "kalibrierprotokoll_lx_punkte" kp as  klp`
I am using postresql and DBeaver - v21.3.0.
 Use this instead of above : `select  "columnName" from "kalibrierprotokoll_lx_punkte" as  klp`